# I need to add co-organizer in teams meeting through graph api

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, graph-explorer

I am using the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/ endpoint
This is my json code:

```
{
'subject': 'Test meeting',
'body': {
    'contentType': 'HTML',
    'content': 'Group code: Hello'
},
'start': {
    'dateTime': '2023-02-25T12:30',
    'timeZone': 'Europe/Sofia'
},
'end': {
    'dateTime': '2023-02-25T13:30',
    'timeZone': 'Europe/Sofia'
},
'attendees': [
    {
        'status': {
            'response': 'accepted',
            'time': '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z'
        },
        'emailAddress': {
            'address': 'name@example.com',
            'name': 'Name'
        },
        'type': 'required'
    }
],
'allowNewTimeProposals': true,
'isOnlineMeeting': true,
'onlineMeetingProvider': 'teamsForBusiness'
}
```

It successfully makes a meeting and adding the participants to it, but I need to assign the participants a role 'co-organizers'. Please help!

I have tried searching on the forums, I have read the whole ms graph documentation, there is no info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re using the [create event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events) endpoint. This has no way to change the meeting options. It’s not a meeting endpoint. It’s the events endpoint that has an option to also create a basic online meeting for the event.

For changing the meeting options, you should search for the meeting id and then call the [update onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-update) endpoint. That does allow setting all the properties you need.

You won't get the correct id to edit the meeting when creating the event (which is a shame and would help a lot when you want to do these kind of things).

1. Create the event with on of the event endpoints like [create event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events)
2. Fetch the correct online meeting id, with the code in [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#code-try-2)
   `GET /me/onlineMeetings?$filter=JoinWebUrl%20eq%20'{joinWebUrl}'`
3. Update the correct meeting with the [update onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint.

Comment: If I'm using the create event endpoint, I cannot update that event via the update onlineMeeting. What should I do in this case? I cannot entirely abandon the create event endpoint and switch to onlineMeeting, because they are not the same. The first creates a "meeting" and the second creates a "live event", which behave differently.

It looks like create event has no control over anything related to the actual meeting (except setting participants), which sucks.

Comment: You can still use the event endpoint to create the event and then use the online meeting endpoint to set the role of the second user. Or maybe create a "user voice" that you want to do this on one go

Comment: Stephan, I believe that is not possible. If I grab the URL of the event and use a PATCH to update it through the online meeting endpoint, it tells me that is not a live event, i.e. can't be manipulated through that endpoint. But I am going to try again since you mentioned it.

Comment: I have to correct myself. It is indeed possible to update a meeting created through the event endpoint, on the online meeting endpoint. Thanks Stephan.